# remove all child nodes with specfic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have dynamic ul li nodes that make tree and i want to remove all child span nodes which have

```
class="highlight" or
class="add_action" or
class="delete_action" or
class="edit_action"
```

under specfic li  with specfic id -(in this example 20 )- i tried this code with jquery to find all span with theses classes to remove it but it didnt worked

```
$('li#20').find('span.add_action').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

also tired

```
   $('li#20').eq(0).find('.add_action').remove();

  $('li#20').children('.add_action').remove();
```

this the full example

https://jsfiddle.net/kqagjtmr/

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery in that fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` attributes in your code, for example:

```
<li class="thide" id="20"><span class="vertical"></span>

<span id="20" class="first_name" title="">الجد  سعد</span>
```

This is why `$('li#20')` doesn't work properly. `id` attributes must be unique, and shouldn't start with a number, either. Use classes instead.

To [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) elements, simply use:

```
$('someSelector').remove();
```

Also, you should include jQuery in your fiddle, you can find the option here:

[image]

Comment: You are awesome +1 for you man :). I know I am not OP but i like your answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Get all the `span` elements having the specified class and remove all of those. No need of using `each` to looping. Use the `span` elements comma-separated to select all the matching elements.

```
$('li#20')
    .find('span.highlight, span.add_action, span.delete_action, span.edit_action')
    .remove();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kqagjtmr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

See the updated fiddle : "https://jsfiddle.net/kqagjtmr/1/"

Use     `$('li#20').find("highlight add_action delete_action edit_action").remove();`

to find multiple elements at once and remove them.